# How to make a phone w/ VB?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to make a phone.It should have 14 buttons (0-9,*,#, "Dial", "End" ) and a label (the answer). If all you clicked were number, then when u click dial, the label should show you this message "DIALING...". If there's * or #, then a message will pop up "Please enter a number" when you click dial.

I got this far.

```visualbasic
  Private Sub btn0_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
    Const int0 As Integer = 0
    lblinput.Text &= int0
End Sub

Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Const int1 As Integer = 1
    lblinput.Text &= int1
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    Const int2 As Integer = 2
    lblinput.Text &= int2
End Sub

Private Sub btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    Const int3 As Integer = 3
    lblinput.Text &= int3
End Sub

Private Sub btn4_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
    Const int4 As Integer = 4
    lblinput.Text &= int4
End Sub

Private Sub btn5_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    Const int5 As Integer = 5
    lblinput.Text &= int5
End Sub

Private Sub btn6_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    Const int6 As Integer = 6
    lblinput.Text &= int6
End Sub

Private Sub btn7_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    Const int7 As Integer = 7
    lblinput.Text &= int7
End Sub

Private Sub btn8_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
    Const int8 As Integer = 8
    lblinput.Text &= int8
End Sub

Private Sub btn9_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
    Const int9 As Integer = 9
    lblinput.Text &= int9
End Sub

Private Sub btn10_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn10.Click
    Dim str10 As String = btn10.Text
    lblinput.Text &= str10
End Sub

Private Sub btn11_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn11.Click
    Dim str11 As String = btn11.Text
    lblinput.Text &= str11

End Sub

Private Sub btnEnd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnd.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub btnDial_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDial.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, this is an English-only site, and "Pls" is not English.

Comment: Well I don't know what to do next. I'm stuck on this part "If all you clicked were number, then when u click dial, the label should show you this message "DIALING...", if however there's * or #, then a message will pop up "Please enter a number" when you click dial."

Comment: Hint: use an `If` statement. Do you have a book on VB.NET programming?

Comment: If you need help with your homework, you should ask your instructor or teaching assistant. Instruction and assistance from them is what your tuition dollars pay for, and you should make them earn it.

Comment: The thing is this is an "extra" credit project for smart students. And I'm above average at vb in my class, so all I need are some examples and hints. That's why I'm seeking for help. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need your hand held then - if you're so above average, you shouldn't need any "examples and hints".

Comment: I'm still in programming I and have only know vb for about 2 weeks . If you don't want to help then please get out. I didn't ask for your help anyway. This is suppose to be a group project and the first group that finish this will get extra credits. However, my group members are too lazy to do it.I'm not doing this for them, I'm doing this for me. And I'm a kind of student who can remember + apply something after I have seen it once.

Comment: You did ask for my help, you posted on this website. And your question was very lazy. "here's what I have to do, here's all my code". I'd quite like you to "get out" until you can learn to ask proper questions.

Comment: Sorry. *You asked* for help here, and you need to be polite. The [faq] clearly describes what behavior is acceptable here, and being rude to people you're asking for free help is not only unacceptable, it's just a bad idea (it makes others not want to help you either). Comments like "If you don't want to help then get out" work both ways - if you don't want to be polite and respectful to others here, perhaps you should look for help somewhere else. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CLUES**

To test if input is all numbers you could use Regular Expression:

```
 Regex.IsMatch(lblinput.Text, "^[0-9]+$")
```

To test if it contains something you could use the Contain method of a string:

```
 myString.Contains("#")
```

Comment: Um nothing show up in the label when i click "DIAL"...

Comment: put the message on your Label. Let's say if your label is lblMessage then put the message in that label like lblMessage.Text = "Dialing..."